# Сохранение состояний recyclerview во фрагменте в Android Paging Library 3

Tags: android, recyclerview

Проблема с библиотекой Android Paging Library 3, настраивал пейджер, работает, но, когда пользователь нажимает кнопу назад, список recyclerview очищается и снова загружается данные (lifecycle не реагирует, state сбрасывается).
Искал в Гитхабе, не нашел нужного решения.

```
    class TracksFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FeatureTracksFragmentBinding

    private val tracksViewModel by lazy { ViewModelProvider(this).get(TracksViewModel::class.java) }

    private lateinit var tracksAdapter: TracksAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.feature_tracks_fragment, container, false)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        return binding.root
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        setAdapter()
        setRecyclerView()
        fetchTracks()
    }

    private fun setAdapter() {
        tracksAdapter = TracksAdapter()
        tracksAdapter.trackSelectedListener = object : TracksAdapter.TrackSelectedListener {
            override fun onTrackSelected(track: Track, imageView: ImageView) {

                val action = TracksFragmentDirections.actionTracksFragmentToPlaybackActivity()

                findNavController().navigate(action)

            }
        }
    }

    private fun setRecyclerView() {
        binding.featureTracksRv.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            adapter = tracksAdapter
        }

        binding.featureTracksRv.adapter = tracksAdapter.withLoadStateHeaderAndFooter(
                header = TracksLoadingAdapter { tracksAdapter.retry() },
                footer = TracksLoadingAdapter { tracksAdapter.retry() }
        )
    }

    private fun fetchTracks() {

        tracksViewModel.fetchTracks().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                tracksAdapter.submitData(it)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

TracksViewModel

```
 public class TracksViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val tracksRepository = TracksRepository.getInstance()

    fun fetchTracks(): LiveData<PagingData<Track>> {

        return tracksRepository.letTracksLiveData()
                .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
    }
}
```

TracksRepository

```
  class TracksRepository {

    companion object {
        const val DEFAULT_PAGE_INDEX = 1
        const val DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE = 20

        //get doggo repository instance
        fun getInstance() = TracksRepository()
    }

    private var client: OvozzWebservice = OvozzRetrofitClient().ovozzWebservice

    //for live data users
    fun letTracksLiveData(pagingConfig: PagingConfig = getDefaultPageConfig()): LiveData<PagingData<Track>> {
        return Pager(
                config = pagingConfig,
                pagingSourceFactory = { TracksPagingSource(client) }
        ).liveData
    }

    /**
     * let's define page size, page size is the only required param, rest is optional
     */
    private fun getDefaultPageConfig(): PagingConfig {
        return PagingConfig(pageSize = TracksRepository.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE, enablePlaceholders = true)
    }
}
```

TracksAdapter

```
  internal class TracksAdapter : PagingDataAdapter<Track, TracksAdapter.TrackViewHolder>(DiffUtilCallbackTracks()) {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TracksAdapter.TrackViewHolder, position: Int) {
        getItem(position)?.let { holder.bindTrack(it) }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TracksAdapter.TrackViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_list_track, parent, false)
        return TrackViewHolder(itemView)
    }


    inner class TrackViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        private val coverImageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.track_cover)
        private val titleTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.track_title)
        private val artistTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.track_artist_name)
        private val trackLayout: ConstraintLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.track_layout)

        fun bindTrack(track: Track) {
            titleTextView.text = track.title
            artistTextView.text = track.getArtists()
            coverImageView.apply {
                transitionName = track.coverUri
                Glide.with(context)
                        .load(track.coverUri)
                        .apply(RequestOptions()
                                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_outline_person_outline_24)
                                .error(R.drawable.ic_outline_person_outline_24)
                        )
                        .into(this)
            }
            trackLayout.setOnClickListener {
                trackSelectedListener.onTrackSelected(track, coverImageView)
            }
        }
    }

    interface TrackSelectedListener {
        fun onTrackSelected(artist: Track, imageView: ImageView)
    }

    lateinit var trackSelectedListener: TrackSelectedListener

}
```

TracksPagingSource

```
class TracksPagingSource(private val ovozzService: OvozzWebservice) :
    PagingSource<Int, Track>() {


    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Track> {
        return try {


            //for first case it will be null, then we can pass some default value, in our case it's 1
            val page = params.key ?: DEFAULT_PAGE_INDEX
            val response = ovozzService.getTracks(page, params.loadSize)

            LoadResult.Page(
                response ?: listOf(),
                prevKey = if (page == DEFAULT_PAGE_INDEX) null else page - 1,
                nextKey = if (response.isEmpty()) null else page + 1
            )
        } catch (exception: IOException) {
            return LoadResult.Error(exception)
        } catch (exception: HttpException) {
            return LoadResult.Error(exception)
        }
    }

    override val keyReuseSupported: Boolean = true
}
```